# How to change the original root name to "legal path" when upgrading to Apache IoTDB V1.0?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I recently updated Apache IoTDB from Version 0.13 to Version 1.0. I use the same root name from the same data, but there was this error: "root.093fb3f0-1ebf-11ed-a398-779d162994d2.04b70ba0-1ecc-11ed-95ac-a371ce2bfa37 is not a legal path". Is this path not supported now and how should I correct it?

I checked the official guide of IoTDB, but did not find relevant answer to this specific path. Wonder if someone can answer my question directly based on the path name I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use "root.`093fb3f0-1ebf-11ed-a398-779d162994d2.04b70ba0-1ecc-11ed-95ac-a371ce2bfa37` ". After updating to Apache IoTDB Version 1.0, if you do not use the ` symbol can cause problems, so it is necessary to avoid creating such time series if you do not want to use backquotes.